# Name of a category of smooth paths between points "enriched" with differential information

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, definition, fundamental-groups

> **$\mathcal Q1$ Question.** *I'm not entirely sure about the definition of this object. I bet that it has to be well known and has a name but I have
> no clue. So the question is for **terminology**, **references** for **this** structure
> **or** **some similar structure** that capture the spirit of my definition.*

It should be a category that has as objects "*points of a space*" and as arrows "*smooth paths between them*". But attached to every point there has to be some additional information of the slope and "the higher slopes" so that two paths can be composed only if the first ends with the same direction, speed (and so on) of how the second starts.

> **$\mathcal Q2$ Side questions:** I know this can be vague. $(2.a)$ If this construction has not a name (maybe because it doesn't exists) can the definition be
> fixed to obtain something close to the desired object **(*)**? $(2.b)$ Are there other
> categories that capture a similar idea?

---

**More informations**

Let me try to define this kind of structure by approximations.
A first good approximate picture is the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$ but it is not exactly like that even if I don't know exactly the technical details where my definition could fail.

Take a space $X=\mathbb R^n$ and let $0,1:\bullet\to I=[0,1]$ the two endpoints of the closed unit interval, where $\bullet$ is the singleton. Notation: $!_X$ is a morphism to the singleton and $0_{\mathbb N}:\bullet\to \mathbb N$ is the inclusion of zero.

**First attempt.**  I try to define a category $\mathfrak C_0(X)$ as follows:

- ${\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}:={\mathcal C}(I,X)$ is the set of continuous functions $\gamma:I\to X$
- ${\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}:=\mathcal C(\bullet,X)$
- Define $\partial_0,\partial_1:{\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}\to {\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}$ where for a path $\gamma:I\to X$ $$\partial_i(\gamma):=\gamma\circ i=\gamma(i)$$
- Define ${\rm id}:{\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}\to {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}$ where for each point ${\bf x}:\bullet\to X$ $${\rm id}_{\bf x}:={\bf x}\,\,\circ \,\,!_I$$
- Define composition as $\circ:{\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}\times_{\partial_0,\partial_1} {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}\to {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}$, s.t. given $\partial_0(\beta)=\partial_1(\gamma)$

$$\beta\circ\gamma(t)=\gamma(2t)\quad \text{if } t\in[0,1/2];\\ \beta\circ\gamma(t)=\beta(2t-1) \quad \text{if } t\in[1/2,1].$$

This thing is not a category because it is not associative. As far as I understand the classical trick is to take all the arrows up to homotopy achieving associativity up to an "higher morphism of morphisms". I'd like instead, for obvious reasons, to consider two paths equivalent only if they "draw" the same image in $X$ (${\rm im} \gamma={\rm im}\beta$). I guess that the formally this amounts to modding out $\mathcal C(I,X)$ by the right action of the group of auto-homeomorhisms $\mathcal C(I,I)$ that fix the endopoints.

$$[\gamma]:=\{\beta\,:\,\exists i:I\to I.\beta\circ i=\gamma\}$$

I'm not sure everything works, probably the definition of composition should be tweaked.
But I try to define the category of smooth paths now.

**Second attempt.**  I try to define a category $\mathfrak C_\infty(X)$ as follows: define $\gamma'(0)$ to be the right hand derivative and $\gamma'(1)$ the left hand derivative.

- ${\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}:={\mathcal C}^\infty(I,X)$ is the set of smoothfunctions $\gamma:I\to X$
- ${\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}:=X^{\mathbb N}$
- Define $\partial_0,\partial_1:{\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}\to {\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}$ where for a path $\gamma:I\to X$ $$\partial_i(\gamma):=(\gamma(i),\gamma'(i),\gamma''(i),...,\gamma^{[n]}(i),...)$$

At this point I'm lost because only the points of the form $k:X\to X^{\mathbb N}:{\bf x}\mapsto ({\bf x},{\bf 0},...,{\bf 0},...)$ are really points. The others are some kind of points enriched with some kind of infinitesimal information. I.e. to get a category we should manually adjoin a bunch of constant paths/morphisms that, even if constant, have non-trivial derivatives at zero. So lets assume we have now ${\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}:={\mathcal C}^\infty(I,X)\sqcup (X^\mathbb N\setminus {\rm im}k)$ where we extend on it $\partial_i$ in the obvious way (identity).

- Define ${\rm id}:{\rm Ob}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}\to {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}$ where for each point ${\bf a}:\mathbb N\to X$ if it is in ${\rm im }k$ $${\rm id}_{\bf a}:={\bf a}\,\circ 0_{\mathbb N} \circ \,\,!_I$$ if it's not then we map to its copy in ${\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_0(X)}$.
- Define composition as $\circ:{\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}\times_{\partial_0,\partial_1} {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}\to {\rm Arr}_{{\mathfrak C}_\infty(X)}$, s.t. given $\partial_0(\beta)=\partial_1(\gamma)$ composition is defined as before: patching paths together when endpoints are compatible.

At this point is not clear to me if we can still mod out by the action of the "smooth automorphisms" of $I$, or something like that, and obtain associativity up to that equivalence relation.

---

**(*) Note on the side questions:** if my definition needs fixes and an improvement or a right definition is proposed, I'd like to have it spelled out.

Comment: I don’t think what you want can be achieved using a category. Composability of arrows in a category is (must be) determined only by the endpoints of the arrows, so you have to either give up having objects = points of the space or give up having a category at all.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks for the comment. I'm sorry but I don't understand the point you are making. In my second attempt I define the objects to be sequences of points so as to record the information of all the higher derivatives. Doing that we clearly have a graph. Then I added manually "infinitesimal constant paths" so that we can have a common section of $\partial_i$ obtaining thus a reflexive graph. Not on the point of the original space. The for the composition I can clearly picture in my mind how to compose those up to an equivalence: two paths are the same if they define the same image on $X$.

Comment: Well, if that is acceptable then you can just do the obvious thing: let the objects be elements of $X \times T X \times T^2 X \times T^3 X \times \cdots$, subject to the obvious consistency conditions, let the morphisms be pairs of (smooth path, length), and let composition be plain concatenation.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is $TX$ the tangent bundle? And isn't this an answer?

Comment: I suspected that something could be rephrased as something involving iteration of some process... but I don't know what the tangent bundle is. I hope @ZhenLin can expand a bit on this definition.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg it would be a partial answer to the side question but not to the main question.

Comment: @ZhenLin What is exactly the obvious thing? Why as morphisms I should take pairs of paths and paths over what? Over that product?

Comment: First make sure you understand the Moore path category concept.